# Can I set an application to launch everytime iOS device is unlocked?

Tags: ios, launch, unlock

Is it possible to set a certain iOS app (with whatever necessary user permissions) to launch automatically each time the phone is unlocked?

Answer (score 2):

No. The only ways to start an app are:

1. from the springboard
2. through a user acting on a local or push notification posted by your app
3. from another app using an URL scheme

Answer (score 0):

Not one that will make it to the appstore...